# Angular - Get Event on Parent Component using routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, routerlink

I'm **emitting** an **event** from **child component** to **parent component** like this

**Child Component**

```
export class ItemComponent {

  @Output() id = new EventEmitter()

  deleteProduct(id) {
    this.id.emit(id)
  }

}
```

**Child Component tag**

```
<app-product-item (id)="getId($event)"></app-product-item>
```

Receive the event on my **Parent Component**

```
getId(id){
  console.log(id)
}
```

This is working fine.

Now I need to have the same behavior but whit a **component** that I access by **routerLink** and not whit a **tag** like `<app-product-item (id)="getId($event)"></app-product-item>` this does not exist because I'm accessing it by **routerLink**.

Routing config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: WinesComponent },
    { path: 'app-wines', component: WinesComponent },
    { path: 'app-about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'app-wine-detail/:id', component: WineDetailComponent },
    { path: 'app-wine-add', component: WineAddComponent }
];
```

Comment: Use services to comunicate between components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` from RxJs to emit/trigger event from one component from another component.

assume we have a service file named
**common.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CommonService {
  constructor() {}
  // Observable User details
  private id = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  id$ = this.id.asObservable();

  // user details
  deleteProduct(id: any) {
    this.id.next(id);
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
import { CommonService } from '../common.service';

constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
  this.commonService.deleteProduct(100); //example id = 100
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```js
import { CommonService } from '../common.service';

constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
  this.commonService.id$.subscribe((id) => {
    // here id = 100 received
    console.log(id); // from child component
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the data through a service to the component you need to access it from.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service